# Dropdown data not changing on change jquery method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

here I am trying to fetch data from states table on the basis of change in country drop down. I am getting internal server error. the id is getting passed to the controller method but data is not returning. 
Here is my code:
View code:

```
  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Country:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">


                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Country, "Id", "Name"), "-- Select Country --", new { @class = "validate[required,maxSize[100]] select  select2insidemodal",@id="country", @onchange = "FillState()" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">State:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">


                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State,
   new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "StateId", "Name"),
          "Select State",
          new { @class = "form-control" })

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Script code:

```
  function FillState() {
        var countryId = $('#country').val();
        console.log(countryId);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/PM/Company/FillState'+'/'+countryId,
            method: "GET",
            //dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (states) {
                console.log(states);

                $("#State").html(""); // clear before appending new list 
                $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                    $("#State").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(state.StateId).html(state.Name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller Method FillState

```
 public ActionResult FillState(int id)
    {
        var states = _stateService.GetStates(id);
        return Json(states,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

state service is returning the values but the return Json is not returning any thing and i get internal server error on console.
When i see ajax request in xhr it show me the following error when i open that request detail:
Server Error in '/' Application.

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.State_6630E5941FBD9204A46907DE2F85C16BCADAC553D22FB81D0F45AD891174D200'.

Please help me in this regard;

Comment: try this : $("#State").append("<option value='" 
                    + state.StateID 
                    + "'>" + state.Name 
                    + "</option>");
            });

Comment: It seems that there are circular references in your object hierarchy which is not supported by the JSON serializer. Do you need all the columns? You could pick up only the properties you need in the view:

return Json(new 
{  
    PropertyINeed1 = data.PropertyINeed1,
    PropertyINeed2 = data.PropertyINeed2
});

This will make your JSON object lighter and easier to understand. If you have many properties, AutoMapper could be used to automatically map between DTO objects and View objects.

Comment: can you please tell the above data.property in my context? I am using automapper and state and country are mapped

Comment: Check below ans for that

Comment: Return a collection of anonymous objects containing just the 2 properties you need (for the option values and display text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below method for that :**

```
public JsonResult FillState(int? CountryId)
{
    var states = _stateService.GetStates().Where(p => p.countryId == CountryId).ToList();
    return Json(new SelectList(states.ToArray(), "StateId", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**And your ajax success function :**

```
 $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                    $("#State").append("<option value='" + state.StateId + "'>" + state.Name + "</option>"); });
                });
```

Comment: Returning an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is unnecessary, and its even more pointless to create a 2nd identical one from the first using `new SelectList(..)`

Comment: Updated now with latest changes.

Comment: Do **not** return a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`!

Comment: We dont have Idea about is .GetStates() is returning List or not I have updated now

Comment: GetSates is returning IEnumerable of State.

Comment: You want single or list of data? because you have used   $.each(states, function (i, state)  in your ajax code seems to be List of data

Comment: Will you please stop constantly pressuring new users to accept your poor quality answers. It certainly does not help others

Comment: @LaxmanGite I want a list of states from dbo.States table against country Id passed.

Comment: Then you have to change here :  var states = _stateService.GetStates().Where(p => p.CountryId == Id).ToList(); and make sure Id should be countryId. Check Updated Ans as well

Comment: yeah i used that in service method GetStates and not here in controller

Comment: and also please change p.StateId to p.countryId